# IMEI number of a mobile phone using python

Tags: python, mobile-phones, imei

How can I get the IMEI number of a mobile phone using Python?

Comment: which mobile, what platform, does it even support python?

Answer (score 0):

Sending `AT+CGSN` through the appropriate serial device will have it return the IMEI.